# Unexplainable 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

For some reason unknown to me, I get this error message:

```
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
> 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
> does not match number of tokens' in /var/www/tools/search.php:56 Stack
> trace: #0 /var/www/tools/search.php(56): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
> #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/tools/search.php on line 56
```

And here's my query:

```
$query = SELECT * FROM renkaat 
INNER JOIN ajoneuvotyypit ON tyyppiID = ajoneuvotyyppiID 
INNER JOIN vuodenajat ON vuodenaikaID = renkaat.vuodenaika 
INNER JOIN valmistajat ON valmistajaID = renkaat.valmistaja
WHERE olemassa = ?  AND ajoneuvontyyppiID = ?
```

The error points to line 56, containing this:

```
$db = $pdo->prepare($query);
$db->execute(array($exec_array));
```

No doubt, the `$exec_array` is the one to blame here. However, when I print the value before executing it, I get `1,1` which should be the correct parameter number.

So what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're wanting to substitute the first parameter with '1' and the second parameter with '1';

If `$exec_array` is already an array with 2 entries you should just do:

```
$db->execute($exec_array);
```

Putting `$exec_array` into an array, makes it an argument to `execute` of an array with a single entry.  Your query is looking for an array of 2 values.

If you run `var_dump($exec_array);`, I'm assuming you get a 2 value array ([0]=>1, and [1]=>1)

If `$exec_array` actually a string '1,1' you need to explode it into an array before using it as parameters to you execute:

```
$exec_array = explode(',', $exec_array);
$db->execute($exec_array);
```

Otherwise using `array($exec_array)` creates just a one entry array `[0]=> '1,1'`

Comment: It's not an array already. It's simply a string of numbers followed by a comma. If I enter `$db->execute(array(1,1));`, I get the same result. But if I change it to that, I get `Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /var/www/tools/search.php on line 56`

Comment: @Christian ah, then you need to explode it

Comment: Are you a god? THANK YOU. That did it. It got trough that error and showed me another with just a typo in the query. Now it works.

Comment: @Christian glad to help, mark my answer as correct if you get a chance.

Comment: Yep, in two minutes! :) It's funny how you try to google the answer for half an hour, then spend five minutes writing a question and get the answer.

Comment: @Christian yes, just happened to be killing a few minutes while I wait on something else to load and saw your issue.  It's the benefit of many eyes...

Comment: Yeah, I've been coding this search for about 4 hours nonstop now, maybe I'll take a break so I can spot my errors :)